# CDI in a servlet produces NullPointerException

Tags: nullpointerexception, cdi

I am trying to use CDI in a servlet, here is a snippet of my servlet code

```
public class MyServlet extends HTTPServlet{

  @Inject
  @Any
  Instance<MyProcedure> procedures;

  public void handleRequest(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res) throws Exception {

    if (procedures == null) {
        System.out.println("procedure list is NULL");
    }
    for (Object o : procedures) {
        System.out.println("calling procedure " + o.toString());
    }
  }
}
```

MyProcedure is am interface and the appliation WAR contains a couple of classes that implement MyProcedure.

I always get a NullPointerException because the list of procedures is null...I do have a beans.xml file in my WEB-INF directory.

Comment: What is the application server? E.g. Tomcat does not support CDI out of the box...

Comment: Using "Object o" to iterate seems like a red flag. as does not checking procedures.isUnsatisfied(). Also please include your verabatim exception.

Comment: Please show your beans.xml.

Comment: Note that if you're deploying to tomcat you'll need to include the CDI binaries, which can be from Weld or OpenWebBeans.

Answer (score 0):

I found out what the problem was. The interface that was implemented by my beans had to be included in the war archive under WEB-INF/lib. After I did that everything started to work as expected.